# What is a non-atomic yield in the context of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

There's a SQL Server performance counter for 'Non-atomic yield rate'.

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190697.aspx) simply states that this is

> Number of non-atomic yields per second.

I'm having trouble finding an explanation for what a non-atomic yield is.

What is a **non-atomic yield** in the context of SQL Server?

Answer (score -1):

The following is what an Atomic block in SQL is:

> Every natively compiled stored procedure contains exactly one block
>   of Transact-SQL statements. This is an ATOMIC block.

This is how Atomic blocks relate to transactions and error handling:

BEGIN ATOMIC

> If a transaction already exists on a session (because a batch executed
>   a BEGIN TRANSACTION statement and the transaction remains active),
>   then starting an atomic block will create a savepoint in the
>   transaction. If the block exits without an exception, the savepoint
>   that was created for the block commits, but the transaction will not
>   commit until the transaction at the session level commits. If the
>   block throws an exception, the effects of the block are rolled back
>   but the transaction at the session level will proceed, unless the
>   exception is transaction-dooming. For example a write conflict is
>   transaction-dooming, but not a type casting error.

[Atomic Blocks in Native Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn452281.aspx)

Comment: I don't think this is the same as a yield, atomic or not.

Comment: Atomic blocks were introduced in in memory OLTP (2014).  "Non-atomic yield rate" has been around since at least SQL Server 2005.